# SMTP pro configuration shows blank screen and can't send mail

Tags: magento-1.9, email, order-email, smtp

When i go to System > Configuration > SMTP Pro it shows me a blank page without any information or errors. It was working great before!

I downloaded the full site, database and imported the theme, in localhost it's working! I have configuration and i can send mails.
I have this problem with other smtp extensions, blank screen or can't send email.
Is it server problem? something is not installed?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Hi I just had the same problem. with Magento 1.9.1.2 and install SMTP pro.
I reinstalled and installed several times and cleared caches.

Once installed the webscreen for the admin section was blank. I kept the magento connect webpage opened and used another one for the admin menus.

To solve, I uninstalled the SMTP Pro, switched to the admin page, went to System->Tools->Compilaton and clicked disable. Then I reinstalled the module.